# Tips to create a cool menu bar with semi-transparent drop downs such as...(see below)

Tags: jquery-ui, html, css

Can someboy tell me how I can acheive the following or somethnig similar for a cool menu bar, etc,.?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pretty much any CSS-based menu system and customize it to look like this using CSS3's `opacity` function, as follows:

```
.dropdown
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Apply this CSS class to the dropdowns in your menu system and you're ready to go.